# Database design for a Test Data with nearly 80 readings

Tags: database-design

I have to design a databse for the following situation.

The data which I have is a test data which we get as a part of our testing process.

I have a set of data with nearly 80 columns. First column is the # No, second is the time, next 10-15 are the enviormental factors like temperature,pressure,humidity etc. Rest 64 are the readings which we get from other measuring instruents.(No of columns will be constatnt)

We will be doing similar test on a weekly basis. Currently the data is stored in an excel workbook. (1 workbook for each test).

I have to develop a database in access so as to use queries on this test data.

Please guide me on how to design the database, whether to put all data in a single table or to split the data into 2-3 tables.

Answer (score 1):

A two-table approach seems simplest here.

Have a `Test` table which represents a test (including fields such as the date the test happened on, the name of that test, and so on), and a `Reading` table which contains all 80 columns, plus an additional column that references the primary key of the test table (meaning "this reading is part of that test").

From what you describe, there would be no benefit to split the 80 columns into several tables.